# Raspberry Pi3 conflicting overlays

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, touchscreen, rfid

I have a Rpi3 with 2016-03-18-raspbian-jessie.
I want to simultaneously connect a RC522 RFID Reader and a 5" touch screen LCD (waveshare).

With this config.txt the 522 reader works fine:

```
dtparam=spi=on
device_tree_param=spi=on
dtoverlay=spi-bcm2708
```

With this config.txt tge LCD works fine:

```
dtparam=spi=on
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
dtoverlay=ads7846,cs=1,penirq=25,penirq_pull=2,speed=50000,keep_vref_on=0,swapxy=0,pmax=255,xohms=150,xmin=200,xmax=3900,ymin=200,ymax=3900
dtoverlay=w1-gpio-pullup,gpiopin=4,extpullup=1
```

But when I combine them the reader cannot work, my test program says 'device not found'. I think that there is a conflict between spi-bcm2708 and ads7846, because when I comment the later (#dtoverlay=ads7846...) it works (but no touchscreen functionality of course). How to solve this?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue, edit in your MFRC522 library a line of spidev code for 1.0. Add dtoverlay = spi1-3cs to the /boot/config.txt file. 
Edit or reduce reader 22 reset to any other GPIO in the MFRC522 library.